<Marquee> tag from left
If marquee is running from >>>>> direction right I can stop at with width %. But if running from left it begins from the specified width. How can i stop at specific point from left direction.
<marquee class="m" style= "color:#a4ac86;padding: 10px; text-align: left"; direction="left" scrollamount="15" > <pre>  Welcome to Garden                                    Welcome to Garden                                    Welcome to Garden                                       Welcome to Garden  </pre><hr> </marquee>

I expect it to start from right to left but stop at specified position.

As marquee is deprecated and may disappear this is probably a good time to convert to using CSS animations.

What can css animation do you recommend?

For that you have to use width stylesheet


div {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 250px;
}

marquee {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
<div>
  <marquee class="m" direction="left" scrollamount="15">
    Lorem Ipsum
  </marquee>
</div>




For left to right width works. I want to do from right to left. But when I give width then it begins from the width provided. I want to start from right and end at the point specified.

@Sinn, Sorry for misunderstanding, Here I update my answer & please verify it. For this we need parent div tag with  margin-left: auto & width stylesheets.

can you write snippet so I can understand better. Thank you.

@Sinn, I updated my answer, please verify it.

oh ok. It works. Thanks
